# Deutsch texts not displayed properly in Chrome

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, localization, gatsby

I have a statically generated website with GatsbyJS. It uses react-intl for a localization but I don't think this is causing a problem.

When I open the website (it is hosted on AWS S3) for the first time it usually displays german transcription very well, but when I open developer tools and refresh the page the transcriptions are often broken (the specific German letters are not displayed properly).

Transcriptions are stored in a js file.

Steps that I use to reproduce the error:

1. I reopen the browser and go to the website. If I see correct texts I then open the dev tools and go to *Application => Frames section => Scripts dropdown* and I see:

[image]

2. Then I refresh the page (sometimes more than once) and somehow texts are now broken:

[image]

Note that this is the same static file!

- It seems that this is only appearing in Chrome.
- When I build and run website locally then it seems to always work (which then would suggest it's not chrome fault).

Not sure where might be the problem

Comment: Looks like the page doesn't specify an encoding and leaves the browser to guess.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that javascript files didn’t have charset set in Content-type header in a response. Locally they had:

Content-Type: javascript; charset=utf-8;

And it worked fine but when they get uploaded to AWS S3 the charset field has been stripped out leaving only:

Content-Type: javascript;

Chrome seems to be more restrictive about it.